# Cant write to cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get data from every other sheet in the workbook and paste it into a master sheet (Sheet1), but when I run my code nothing happens, Can someone tell me why this is?

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Text = "Started"
i = 1
'cells is row,col
For Each objWorksheet In wb.Worksheets
    'ws.Cells(1, i).Value = objWorksheet.Name
    'objWorksheet.Activate
    'ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    doJStuff i, objWorksheet
    i = i + 1
Next
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Text = "DONE"
End Sub

Sub doJStuff(row, ws)
    ws.Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
'end paste name
'copy post history and transpose into row 2 on sheet1
    ws.Select
    Range("H2:H30").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 2).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
'end post history
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a number of problems with your code. First of all, avoid using Select wherever possible. Second, you are not properly assigning variables. You should put `Option Explicit` on the top of the module and then make sure you've assigned things correctly.

As for the actualy code, when you are copying/pasting the H2:H30 range into your first sheet you are going to only end up getting the first value in the range for every sheet except the last because you are pasting 28 rows but only incrementing the destination row by one. I didn't fix that but it's worth pointing out. I also left in your comments though they don't make much sense. Without knowing what you are trying to do, I've only cleaned up some of your code but it probably still won't work exactly right.

```
Sub YourSub()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wksht As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Text = "Started"
i = 1
'cells is row,col
For Each wksht In Worksheets
    'ws.Cells(1, i).Value = objWorksheet.Name
    'objWorksheet.Activate
    'ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    doJStuff i, wksht
    i = i + 1
Next
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Text = "DONE"
End Sub

Sub doJStuff(row As Integer, ws As Worksheet)
    ws.Range("A2").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 1).PasteSpecial
'end paste name
'copy post history and transpose into row 2 on sheet1
    ws.Range("H2:H30").Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
'end post history
End Sub
```